# Where did $u(t) = e^{-3t}$ came from this given solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This problem and solution is from the Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Feedback and Control Systems (3rd edition). The problem is:

3.22. Find the forced response of the differential equation:

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 4\frac{dy}{dt}+4y=3 \frac{du}{dt} +2u$

where $u(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-3t}, t \geq 0.$

I'm not asking to solve it for me, merely point me in the right direction. It might be possible that $u(t)$ is given by the problem but I'm also asking if it is also possible to derive it based from the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: The equation itself poses no restrictions on $u(t)$.

Comment: So we can't get the value given for u(t) from the equation?

Comment: That's like asking if the equation $y=f(x)$ determines the function $f(x)$.  It doesn't.  All it does it establish a connection between $y$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Have a good day.

Comment: Consider equation $x+2=a$ where $a=3$. $a=3$ does not follow from equation, it is part of problem statement.